# How to read variables having superscript? Also how to read those with both super- and subscript?

Tags: notation, education

To read $x_i$, we say "$x$ sub $i$".
How do we read $x^i$ where $i$ is not a exponent number and is just a superscript for the variable $x$?
How do we read a variable when having both super- and subscript as in $x_i^n$?

Comment: I personally read it "$x$ super $n$ sub $i$"

Comment: I often read $x_i$ as simply "ex eye"; likewise, $x^n$ as "ex enn" (for superscript-not-exponent $n$). With $x_i^n$, I might say either "ex eye enn" or "ex enn eye", depending upon whether the $i$ or $n$ had precedence in the given context.

Comment: @saulspatz and Blue I appreciate your answers.